# dplyr::str_replace: how to reuse the pattern in the replacement?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse, str-replace

Is there a way to reuse the regex pattern when searching text to replace using `dplyr::str_replace()` (or `replace_all()`)?

E.g.: change 'apple' to 'apples': this would require adding 's' to the search pattern 'apple', like `str_replace_all(string = data, pattern = "apple", replacement = pattern"s")`, with obviously something else as 'pattern'

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: `str_replace_all("O have got apple", "apple", "\\0s")`